# Como pegar ID de inputs gerados dentro de DIV dinamicamente''

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber como faço para conseguir pegar os ID de inputs hidden que foram gerados dinamicamente dentro de DIV via Jquery.

Já tentei da seguinte forma porém não dá certo:

```
$(document).on('click', '.div_desc_prod', function() {
    alert($(".id_produto").val());
});
```

Onde a .div_desc_prod é referente a cada div gerada dinamicamente e .id_produto é referente a cada input gerado dentro de cada div dinamicamente.

---

Acho que não consegui expressar bem o meu caso... Eu não preciso gerar as DIVs com ID's dinâmicos, as DIV's são geradas a partir de uma seleção no Menu, por exemplo, ao selecionar no Menu a Categoria de Pizzas Tradicionais, será gerado na tela a quantidade de DIV com cada Pizza dentro dessa categoria em cada DIV, e em cada DIV já possui um input hidden com o ID de cada pizza listada. Então eu preciso selecionar o ID da pizza desejada ao clicar sobre a DIV para jogar no carrinho de compras.

---

Não é somente 1 ID, pode haver 1 ou vários, por exemplo:

```
<div class="div_desc_prod" id="div_desc_produto">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_produto" value="'+ obj.id +'">
</div>
```

Essa div pode ser gerada 1 ou várias vezes com diferentes IDs, dai quando clicar em uma determinada DIV quero pegar o ID daquela que está sendo clicada.

Comment: Evite criar novas respostas para atualizar a pergunta faça um edição, com o link [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o $(this) para aceder ao elemento onde clicou. Depois é só procurar o elemento input dentro desse elemento e obter o valor.

Pegando no seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
$(document).on('click', '.div_desc_prod', function() {
    alert($(this).find("input").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se for um ID mesmo, tem que ser assim:

`alert($("#id_produto").val());`

Atualizando:

```
var html;
for(var i=0; i<=$('.div_desc_prod').length; i++){
       html = '<div class="div_desc_prod" id="div_desc_produto'+i+'">'+
              '<input type="hidden" name="id_produto" value="'+ obj.id +'">'+
              '</div>';
       $('.container').append(html);
}
```